# Skype + webcam recommendations

Tags: skype, webcam

I'm looking for a webcam for use with Skype which has a built in microphone.

I specifically want to be able to use the microphone in the camera when i'm taking calls which aren't video calls on skype. Are they any that do this?  Does the microsoft H5D Life Camera do this?  The operating environment is windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a [Logitech QuickCam Pro 5000](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/435/243) since early 2007. It has worked flawless on XP32, Vista-x64 and Win7x64. It works swell as a mic only in Skype and other applications if that's what you want.

It's not cheap but well worth it in my opinion